# Correlation between high cpu/ram usage and poor computer performance

Tags: performance

I'm researching electromigration and the effects of high cpu/ram usage on a computer.

There are tons of discussions on these topics taking place via forums and message boards, but I am looking for credible sources that are backed by metrics.

Comment: This seems to be a question about electronics and possibly system design but I don't see any computer science.

Comment: Really? This is not computer science? Does hardware escape the study of computer science? I thought I had selected the most appropriate sub for the question. My apologies. Where would you recommend I discuss such questions in the future?

Comment: Computer science deals with a certain level of abstraction. In particular, we assume that computers work and ask what you can do with them. Producing an actual working computer is a matter of engineering. I agree that you're talking about essentially doing scientific experiments on computers so yes, you're asking about computers and science but not about [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science). I'm honestly not sure what the best place to ask this question would be. [electronics.se] Stack Exchange is a possibility..

Answer (score 2):

There's a [general-interest article from the IEEE about transistor aging](http://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/processors/transistor-aging/0) that's based on the paper ["An Array-Based Odometer System for Statistically Significant Circuit Aging Characterization"](https://netfiles.umn.edu/users/kimxx624/www/papers/2011/JSSC11_Odometer.pdf) (2011) by Keane, Zhang, and Kim. They present:

> A system that facilitates efficient statistical aging measurements involving the mechanisms of bias temperature instability (BTI) and hot carrier injection (HCI) stress.

Roberto Lacerda de Orio's dissertation ["Electromigration Modeling and Simulation"](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/orio/diss_html.html) (2010) has a comprehensive treatment of the physics of electromigration, as well as a numerical model and "several simulation studies of electromigration".

You may find more references in [this SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/456445/is-the-performance-of-a-cpu-affected-as-it-ages).